# How can I check for cheating in assignments given by Learning management system

Tags: sharepoint-2010, canvas-lms

I am using SP based learning management system where I ask students to submit assignments via LMS. However I suspect that many people copy and submit almost identical answers. How can check if they copied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many tools in market offer anti-plagiarism checkers. If you are using SharePoint LMS you can choose between three anti-plagiarism systems: Ephorus, Turnitin and Urkund. These have an inbuilt support. 
See link http://www.elearningforce.com/products/Documents/Plagiarismtools_and_SharePointLMS_2010.pdf